# using lambdas as operators for "foldr"

Tags: haskell

So i'm following a course on Haskell, and came across defining the length function with the foldr function

so, as the length is not a primitive recursive function, we have to be more specific with the "operator" we're passing to it and, in the course, the end result is this:

```
len :: [a] -> Int
len = foldr (\_ n -> n + 1) 0
```

I think i understand the end result, but i really need clarification on the signature of the lambda function:

- the underscore argument is supposed to be the value, which we don't care for
- the n argument is the return of the previous call

am i right to think of it this way? or something different is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption are correct:

- We don't care about the elements of the list, so we can ignore them and make this clear with the underscore.
- The `n` is indeed the return value of the previous call of the function. It can also be named `acc` standing for *accumulator* which makes its meaning more clear.

To be precise, as Carl pointed out, in the case of `foldr`, `n` is a thunk of nested calls of the function on elements of the list that will, if evaluated, do recursive evaluation. Thus `n` becomes the result of the recursive calls to `foldr`.

For visualization purposes:

```
-- how `foldr (+) 0 [1..5]` unfolds
λ> foldr (\x y -> "( " ++ x ++ " + " ++ y ++ " )") "0" $ map show [1..5]
"( 1 + ( 2 + ( 3 + ( 4 + ( 5 + 0 ) ) ) ) )"
-- how `foldl (+) 0 [1..5]` unfolds
λ> foldl (\x y -> "( " ++ x ++ " + " ++ y ++ " )") "0" $ map show [1..5]
"( ( ( ( ( 0 + 1 ) + 2 ) + 3 ) + 4 ) + 5 )"
```

Comment: i understand that, but you're not answering my question

Comment: oh, yeah, cool. So in a way, it works like a reduce method

Comment: exactly, it's like a js reduce

Comment: The seed value needs to be `0` instead of `1`. Otherwise an empty list will have a length of 1.

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez JS's `reduce` is a fold, but it's a left fold rather than a right fold.

Comment: you are correct @GoodNightNerdPride thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @molbdnilo hmm, have to think about that one :)

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez to see the difference of `foldr` and `foldl` visualized run the following 2 expressions: `foldr (\x y -> "( " ++ x ++ " + " ++ y ++ " )") "0" $ map show [1..5]` and `foldl (\x y -> "( " ++ x ++ " + " ++ y ++ " )") "0" $ map show [1..5]`

Comment: I slightly object to calling `n` "the result of the previous call to the function". That implies an ordering that's inaccurate in Haskell in general. It's a thunk that will, if evaluated, do recursive evaluation. I think it would be most accurate to call it "the result of the recursive call to `foldr`."

Comment: hello @Carl I just edited the answer to add your point. I didn't edit the original statement to keep it simple for the beginner and then add more complicated details. Please have a look and let me know if I haven't conveyed your point precisely. Thanks.

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez I've always found [these diagrams](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/COMP1100-PAL/comp1100-pal.github.io/master/_posts/2020-04-27-foldl-vs-foldr.png) to be helpful for visualizing left and right folds. Note that a list consists of `[]` and (possibly) `(:)` applications. So, `[1,2,3,4]` is exactly the same as `1:(2:(3:(4:[])))` (in fact, internally, it gets turned into that by the compiler).

Comment: @DavidYoung thank you, that definitely helps a lot with visualizing. I just haven't had the chance of finding a good usecase for `foldl` so, when i do, i'll definitely come back to this. I already understood the (:) application

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez, `len` is a perfect use case for `foldl'` (the strict version of `foldl`). `foldl` itself is not useful for lists.